# If $\int_0^t \cos(f(t)) \,dt =\frac{l}{v}$ and $\int_0^t \sin(f(t))\, dt =\frac{ut}{v}$, find $t$

Tags: definite-integrals

While solving a physics problem I ended up with the following integration and I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

$$\int_0^t \cos(f(t)) \,dt =\frac{l}{v} $$

And

$$\int_0^t \sin(f(t)) \,dt =\frac{ut}{v} $$

We don't know what $f(t)$ is. We have to eliminate it and find the value of $t$ in terms of $u$, $v$ and $l$.

Note: please let me know if it is not possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides wrt t.
First equation, you get:
$cos(f(t))=\frac {d(\frac l v)} {dt}$
Second equation:
$sin(f(t))=\frac {d(\frac {ut} v )} {dt} $. If u,l,v are constants, then RHS reduce to 0 and u/v respectively.

Comment: I have to find the value of t but it gets eliminated in this method.

Comment: Are l,u,v constants?

Comment: Yes but we don't know f(t)

Comment: I think we can't find t

Comment: I have seen the answer. $t=\frac{lv}{v^2 - u^2}$. Can this be helpful

Comment: May there is problem in your equations. You can post the question in physics stack exchange. Without knowledge of f, we can't find the answer.